# How to use where clause in Query with LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, left-join, where-clause

how to write my sql query correct? I would like to use WHERE clause in query, but I don't know  how is correct. This is my query with mistake:

```
**SELECT pil.[Buy-from Vendor No_],  pil.No_, pil.Amount, pil.Quantity 
FROM dbo.[„blk“ 2011$Purch_ Inv_ Line]AS pil
WHERE pil.Type=5
LEFT JOIN dbo.[„blk“ 2011$Purch_ Inv_ Header] AS pih
ON pil.[Document No_]=pih.No_
ORDER BY pil.amount**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way you have handle left joins

```
SELECT 
    pil.[Buy-from Vendor No_] 
  ,  pil.No_, pil.Amount
  , pil.Quantity 
FROM dbo.[UAB „Arvi cukrus“ 2011$Purch_ Inv_ Line] pil
LEFT JOIN dbo.[„blk“ 2011$Purch_ Inv_ Header] Pih ON pil.[Document No_]=pih.No_
WHERE pil.Type=5
ORDER BY pil.amount
```

Comment: Wrong table names, must be [„blk“ 2011$Purch_ Inv_ Line]

Comment: Change and another table name :) thanks, that could be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `WHERE` clause right before `ORDER BY`.

Here is the documentation that defines how `SELECT` statements should look like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx.

Comment: It is a good advice to verify statement from the MSDN documentation, rather than using word `before` and `after`.

Answer (score 1):

`Where` comes after the `From` clause. The correct query is

```
   SELECT pil.[Buy-from Vendor No_],  pil.No_, pil.Amount, pil.Quantity 
    FROM dbo.[„blk“ 2011$Purch_ Inv_ Line]AS pil
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[„blk“ 2011$Purch_ Inv_ Header] AS pih
    ON pil.[Document No_]=pih.No_
    WHERE pil.Type=5
    ORDER BY pil.amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the where after all the joins:

```
SELECT pil.[Buy-from Vendor No_],  pil.No_, pil.Amount, pil.Quantity 
FROM dbo.[„blk“ 2011$Purch_ Inv_ Line]AS pil
LEFT JOIN dbo.[„blk“ 2011$Purch_ Inv_ Header] AS pih
ON pil.[Document No_]=pih.No_
WHERE pil.Type=5
ORDER BY pil.amoun
```

Answer (score 0):

put `WHERE` just before `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

Move the `WHERE` clause after the `FROM` clause and other table references like so:

```
SELECT 
  pil.[Buy-from Vendor No_], 
  pil.No_, 
  pil.Amount, 
  pil.Quantity 
FROM ...
...
WHERE pil.Type=5
ORDER BY pil.amount
```